# FileReader > ajax triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filereader

I'm implementing a file upload splitter, breaking an uploaded file into pieces with the FileReader API and sending it in separate ajax requests to a backend.

Somehow my file parts are uploaded multiple times with the pattern:

1) slice 0

2) slice 0,1

3) slice 0,1,2

For a larger file this often leads to the browser crashing when a certain number of parallel uploads is reached.

I want to upload one piece at a time, before possibly testing if specifying a defined number of pieces in parallel gives any performance benefits.

The code is as follows:

```
function startFileUpload() {
    if (jQuery('#upload').length) {

        var reader = {};
        var file = {};
        var slice_size = 4000 * 1024;
        var size_done = 0;
        var percent_done;

        reader = new FileReader();
        file = document.querySelector('#upload').files[0];

        upload_file(0);

        function upload_file(start) {
            var next_slice = start + slice_size + 1;
            var blob = file.slice(start, next_slice);
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

            reader.addEventListener("loadend", function () {
                /*reader.onload = function (event) {*/
                if (event.target.readyState !== FileReader.DONE) {
                    return;
                }

                // At this point the file data is loaded to event.target.result
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'https://jvdgj5oln9.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/upload',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
crossDomain: true,
                    data: {
                        action: 'upload',
                        slice_no: (next_slice-1)/slice_size+1,
                        file_data: event.target.result,
                        file: file.name,
                        file_type: file.type
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (size_done < start + slice_size){    
                            size_done = start + slice_size;              //<!--- comment 1
                            percent_done = Math.floor((size_done / file.size) * 100);

                            if (next_slice < file.size) {
                                // Update upload progress
                                jQuery('#upload_progress').html('Uploading File - ' + percent_done + '%');

                                // More to upload, call function recursively
                                upload_file(next_slice);
                            } else {
                                // Update upload progress
                                jQuery('#upload_progress').html('Upload Complete!');
                            }
            }
                    }
                });
            });

        }
    }
}
```

I have checked with Chrome debugger that startUpload is only called once.

I have also checked with the debugger that the code at "comment 1" is not called more than once per slice, however I can see that the ajax request is triggered with 1, then 2, then 3 slices in parallel in the Network tab.

I can't see any JavaScript closures that are self executing either? So I'm not clear which part triggers multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `upload_file()` you hook up a new event listener to `reader.loadend` event.

Since `reader` is defined outside the scope of `upload_file()`, you end up with a bunch of event listeners on the same object.

Either hook up the event listener in `startFileUpload()`, or move `reader` to the `upload_file()` scope.